# Calling subprocess.call hangs when I set the stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a function which I call a progarm, with some args and want to get the result.

When I use the following

```
proc = subprocess.call(["fetch.py", "--cookies=/tmp/tmp-cookies"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
return stdout
```

The app just hangs.
But if I run

```
return subprocess.call(["fetch.py", "--cookies=/tmp/tmp-cookies"])
```

then I get the output on my screen and the app works fine, however I need to get the output into a function.

I am using python 2.6.1, and unable to use check_output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [spec](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) says,

> Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.

What you need instead, is `subprocess.Popen`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["fetch.py", "--cookies=/tmp/tmp-cookies"], 
                       stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
return stdout
```

(Also, `subprocess.call` does not return the process object, only exit status)

Answer (score 0):

Your subprocess must read its stdin before the communication is complete, and the main process can continue. The workaround would be write out in a thread.